# Videos which don't play in Firefox: How to detect and how to fix?

Tags: firefox, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I have, as test cases, two mp4 videos:  they seem to be encoded the same, but one works in Firefox and one doesn't:

bad.mp4 (doesn't work) [view](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yq4i8i6uma9jony/bad.mp4?dl=0) [download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yq4i8i6uma9jony/bad.mp4?dl=1)

good.mp4 (does work) [view](https://www.dropbox.com/s/swkcm9ik3iuc9pc/good.mp4?dl=0) [download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/swkcm9ik3iuc9pc/good.mp4?dl=1)

(NOTE - I thought that the "view" links above would open them using the browser's built-in player, but it looks like they use Dropbox's video player, which DOES work in firefox.  So, to see it in firefox, download it and then drag it into Firefox or right click and choose Firefox from "open with" - thanks!)

They both play in Chrome.

There is a long discussion on the Mozilla bug tracking site about a related issue:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1130450

So, I need to answer three questions:

1) What is the problem with bad.mp4?

2) How can I detect, programmatically (ie at the linux command line) which videos, of a library of videos, are going to have this problem?

3) How can I fix it, programmatically (eg with FFMPEG).

One thing I noticed was that in the good one, the video is on stream 0 and the audio stream 1, while on the bad one it's the other way round.  I tried swapping the streams but it didn't seem to help.

**EDIT**: re the Baseline profile

It was suggested that FF might not like Baseline profile videos.  I was able to identify some baseline profile videos that work and some that don't, so I think that's not the key problem.  Here are a couple more samples:

Baseline_bad.mp4 (doesn't work) [view](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yg35m37efoo9pfe/Baseline_bad.mp4?dl=0) [download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yg35m37efoo9pfe/Baseline_bad.mp4?dl=1)

Baseline_good.mp4 (does work) [view](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qyu5e5f542s7va0/Baseline_good.mp4?dl=0) [download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qyu5e5f542s7va0/Baseline_good.mp4?dl=1)

Comment: @llogan sorry about the link - i've fixed it.  I don't know what you mean about Baseline/Constrained Baseline - can you see how the good one is set in this regard?

Answer (score 2):

First of all sorting mp4 tracks has nothing to do with that. Second, on Win10 with Firefox version 52.5.3 your bad.mp4 works just fine. However on MacOS using Firefox 69.03 bad.mp4 also plays but with a lot of artefacts.

The H.264 bitstream seems to be ok. I demultiplexed the bad mp4 with MP4Box `MP4Box -raw 2 bad.mp4` which gives `bad_track2.h264` and I decoded it with the [reference software](https://github.com/shihuade/JM.git). Decoded just fine, without any problems, so the bitstream seems to be not a problem.

So it has to be the packaging into mp4. And indeed, if I package the bitstream back again using `MP4Box -add bad_track2.h264 repackage.mp4`, it plays just great. So this is a good news, since you don't have to re-encode (transcode) your videos, which will save you a lot of time. 
Of course transcoding also solves it `ffmpeg -i bad.mp4 transcode.mp4` in case you don't want to do it with MP4Box.

To answer 2 and 3. not 100 % sure if this is the same for all of your videos but the difference between good.mp4 and bad.mp4 is the `compatible_brands` which you can get with `ffprobe`. you can write a script which finds the videos with the same brand as in bad.mp4 and re-packages each of them using `ffprobe`, `MP4Box`.

I hope this helps.

### Edit

To address the issue raised in @llogan's answer, regarding the *Baseline AVC* profile. IMHO this is very unlikely that the Baseline Profile is not supported, however can not be 100% sure about it since it may depend on the platform on which the Firefox is running.

From [Mozilla's Web Video codec guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Video_codecs#AVC_(H.264)):

[image: screenshot]

> 1: Firefox support for AVC is dependent upon the operating system's built-in or preinstalled codecs for AVC and its container in order to avoid patent concerns.

Comment: Thanks very much, I will investigate further using these "leads" :)

Comment: Firefox bundles Cisco's AVC decoder, which only [advertises](https://github.com/cisco/openh264/blob/master/README.md) Constrained Baseline support.

Comment: BTW. that Cisco's AVC decoder can also deal with main and high profiles of course.  as described in [releases](https://github.com/cisco/openh264/blob/c2e4abc16641a2c14cec48aef92940503116f4bb/RELEASES)

Comment: came back here to check out the reference which I asked for in my comment but for some reason my comment was deleted?! I wonder why?

Comment: I identified a few videos that had the Baseline profile, but most of these are playable (a couple are not).  So, I think you're right that it's not the Baseline profile that's the problem.  I'll add a working and non-working Baseline video to my question in case that makes it easier to see the key difference.  thanks!

Comment: Regarding the "Baseline_bad.mp4" and "Baseline_good.mp4" videos - the bad one has `compatible_brands = isomavc1mp42` while the good one has `compatible_brands = mp41mp42isom"`.  I'm not sure how to parse this - is this read as "mp41, mp42 and isom", while the bad one is compatible with "isom, avc1, and mp42".  If so, what is the difference between mp41 and mp42, and is it the case the Firefox supports mp41 but not mp42?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I'll try to find some time to check what exactly those brands mean. Have to read the spec for this. But I would guess that the mp4 packager which muxed your bad.mp4 messed up some timings for individual samples. so that the browser is feeding the decoder with NAL units in different order as it should. Did you try to re-package?

Comment: @BungaBunga the repackage (following what you did in your answer) seemed to work - thanks!  It is extremely fast too, compared to re-encoding the video which is the only method i'd previously found to fix it.

My next step is to look at all of our video library and output their compatible_brands into a spreadsheet, to see if this is the critical test between a working and not-working video.  I'll keep you posted, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## What is the problem with `bad.mp4`?

It's not the stream order because you can switch the order in `good.mp4` and it still plays: `ffmpeg -i good.mp4 -map 0:a -map 0:v -c copy switched.mp4`

#### AUD NAL units

`bad.mp4` may contain AUD NAL units Firefox doesn't like.

#### Baseline profile

Perhaps whatever decoder your Firefox is using doesn't like the *Baseline* [H.264 profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding#Profiles). This is not the same as the far more common *Constrained Baseline* profile which is what `good.mp4` is.

I'm not sure what version of Firefox you're using and what OS you are on so it is a guess.

---

## How can I detect this problem?

Use `ffprobe` to determine the profile:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -of csv=p=0 -show_entries stream=profile input.mp4
```

If the issue is due to the AUD NAL units, and all of the Baseline videos have this issue, then this can still be useful. I didn't take the time to investigate further regarding the AUD NAL units so maybe it's a red herring.

---

## How can I fix it?

#### If the AUD NAL units are the issue

Remux using the [h264_metadata](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#h264_005fmetadata) bitstream filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -bsf:v h264_metadata=aud=remove -map 0 -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- This is fast because it avoids re-encoding.
- You'll need FFmpeg 3.4 or later to use this.
- See note below regarding `-movflags +faststart`.

#### If Baseline profile is the issue

You'll have to re-encode the video to change the profile:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more encoding options.
- I added `-movflags +faststart` because it seems like you'll be presenting these videos via progressive download playback. This option will allow the video to begin playing while it is still downloading.

Comment: Thanks - yes, that is th case, thanks, re the internet streaming.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Did you try using `h264_metadata` in my updated answer? It is easier than using MP4Box, it deals with the audio, is one command, and also sets the moov atom to the beginning of the file with `-movflags +faststart`.